# Visual Studio 2012 Stops Matching

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I created the following Regex Find/Replace:

> FROM (\w*) ORDER
>
> FROM $1 WHERE ISNULL(ISARCHIVED, 0) = 0

and every time I run it, it does one replacement. Here is the 'Find Result' window text:

Replace all "FROM (\w*) ORDER", "FROM $1 WHERE ISNULL(ISARCHIVED, 0) = 0 ", Regular expressions, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, ""
C:\Users\ninja\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CCP\CR-DAL\Types\TypeAdmitInitialAssessment.cs(23,50):            return DataTools.GetTable(@"SELECT * FROM TypeAdmitInitialAssessment WHERE ISNULL(ISARCHIVED, 0) = 0  BY SortOrder", false);
Total replaced: 1  Matching files: 1  Total files searched: 1029

Can anyone tell me how to make it keep matching?

Answer (score 0):

use Lazy matching pattern:

```
FROM (\w*?) ORDER

FROM $1 WHERE ISNULL(ISARCHIVED, 0) = 0
```

Comment: still only comes back '1 replacement made' every time I run it :/